# How does Eclipse apply an Expose Package configuration to a Maven build?

Tags: eclipse, maven

How does Eclipse propagate Java 11 "Expose Package..." to the Maven target?

I am exposing a Java 11 module to ALL-UNNAMED using Eclipse: Properties -> Java Build Path -> Module Dependencies -> Expose Package...

Nothing is added to pom.xml with this configuration yet the project builds successfully.

Using Eclipse 2020-06, m2e's maven 3.6.3, maven-compiler-plugin 3.8.1 (this is the only explicit override in pom.xml). The rest is the "EMBEDDED" maven.

When I look at the Maven console and effective pom I do not see any compilerArgs (--add-exports...) added. When I run mvn from the command line I do get compiler failure as expected.

How does m2e propagate --add-exports to javac without it being visible to help:effective-pom target or Maven console?

In Eclipse when I click "Show JPMS Options..." it does display "--add-exports ...", but nowhere in the m2e debug output does this appear.

Answer (score 0):

Say I want to use internal API jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.tool
, add compilerArgs shall work:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <fork>true</fork>
                        <arg>--add-exports</arg>
                        <arg>jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.tool=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

'fork' must be true.